# How do I restore minimized windows behavior?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, ubuntu-mate

My wife (or one of our cats) stroke the wrong combination of keyboard keys and now I'm having a hell of a time to get her windows back to the "old-fashioned minimization style", that is, she wants her minimized windows to be clearly visible in the panel bar, instead of "mysteriously" disappearing out of her sight. She could always recover the minimized windows with Alt+Tab, sure, but that's not what she wants.

**System + Control Center + Keyboard Shortcuts + Window Management** has lots of options and I have disable a couple of them, but nothing works and I'm afraid of going ahead (possibly) causing some system snafu. I was hopeful that disabling "*Hide all normal windows and set focus to the desktop*" would do the magic, but it didn't work.

The computer has the following specs (I've done some research and learnt that this kind of info is important in this specific case):

`Kernel: 5.4.0-47-generic x86_64 bits: 64`

`Desktop: MATE 1.24.0 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you try the Dash to Panel GNOME extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/ ?

Comment: Looks like the "Window list applet" got removed from the panel. Right click the panel, select "+Add to panel", and add the "Window list applet". Alt+Tab should still work, not sure why get rid of it.

Comment: @mikewhatever, thanks, it worked! To "get rid" of Alt+Tab was not exactly what I meant to say; I just wanted to get rid of the _need_ to use Alt+Tab to select a minimized window.